# Receiving simple parameters with webservice

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web-services

I am currently just getting into Web services as it is new to me. I have put together a sample one returning animal type.

```
public class AnimalTypeService {
  public String animalType(String animal) {
    String animalType = "";
    if ("Lion".equals(animal)) {
      animalType = "Wild";
    } else if ("Dog".equals(animal)) {
      animalType = "Domestic";
    } else {
      animalType = "I don't know!";
    }
    return animalType;
  }
}
```

However, I would now like to take several string/parameters. For instance someone who enters in a name, lastname, age, birthday. Can someone give me an example on how I could take in a set of parameters such as these and write them into a xml doc format?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 0):

For taking in multiple parameters you have three options:

1) You could create a class (human for example), which contains the instance variables name last name, age, and birthday.

2) You could pass in the parameters as an ArrayList or as an Array. However, you then have to be careful that the ordering of the parameters fits what you need (so that you don't read in a last name as a birthday for example).

3) You can pass in the parameters as a map, with a key being "name" and a value being "steve" for example. Then the method could search for certain keys and find the values associated with those keys.

In regards to writing them into an xml doc format, i would suggest looking up DOM objects, as they make writing xml docs very simple. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/ provides a great tutorial/example